# Timestamp converter

Tags: java, timestamp

I tried to create an timestamp to Date  and Date to timestamp converter in java. the converter logic works perfectly and I displayed it on a console window. But this works not correctly.

If I type this timestamp into my console window:

```
1449946800000 (I get this timestamp from my calendar web plugin)  

Date : 13.10.2016 20:00:00 (Timezone "Europe/Berlin ) = 1476381600000
```

First time I call a mehtod which required the timestamp format like above.

```
      LongStamp = LongStamp/1000;   

        logic.convertedTime(LongStamp);

        } else {
          .....

        }
```

If match, the method logic.convertedTime(xx) is calling. ( See class convertLogic)

Here is my code:

```
public class convertLogic {

/** TimeZone-Support**/ 
private static final String TIMEZONEBERLIN = "Europe/Berlin";


/**
 * convertedTime:  <br>
 * input timestamp to convert into date <br>
 * <strong>...</strong>
 * @param timestamp 
 */
public void convertedTime(long timestamp) {

    TimeZone timeZoneBerlin = TimeZone.getTimeZone(TIMEZONEBERLIN);
    // System.out.println(timeZoneBerlin.getDisplayName());
    // System.out.println(timeZoneBerlin.getID());
    // System.out.println(timeZoneBerlin.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    Calendar myDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    myDate.setTimeZone(timeZoneBerlin);
    myDate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000);

    int month = myDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int second = Integer.parseInt(leadingZero(myDate.get(Calendar.SECOND)));


    System.out.println("Datum: " + myDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "." + month + "." + myDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            + " " + myDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + myDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
            + second);

}



 /**
 * leadingZero for 2 digit values
 * 
 * @param value
 * @return String
 */
private static String leadingZero(int value) {

    int testValue = value;

    if (testValue < 10) {

        return "0" + value;
    } else {

        return value + "";
    }

}
```

And I get following output:

```
 Datum: 13.10.2016 20:0:0
```

But I want or I need all zeros from the Hour,Minutes and seconds like this :

```
  13.10.2016 20:00:00
```

Does anybody know an solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you calling the method `leadingZero`? Have you tried using the method that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fix: Call your `leadingZero` method

After adding a leading zero you effectively remove it.

After padding with a leading zero, you call `Integer.parseInt`. That call generates a number, an `int`. The default format used when converting that to a String has no leading zero.

Change the data type of `second` to `String`.

Likewise, pass the result of `myDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` to your `leadingZero` method.

## Strange results

I do not understand your input and results. If `1449946800000` is a count of milliseconds from the epoch of first moment of 1970 UTC, that is a date-time in 2015 not 2016:

- `2015-12-12T19:00:00Z`
- `2015-12-12T20:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]`

## java.time

You are working too hard. Use a date-time framework for this work.

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## Example code

First translate your count-from-epoch into an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object representing a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
long input = 1_449_946_800_000L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( input );
```

Apply a time zone, [`Europe/Berlin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe%2FBerlin). A [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) represents the time zone. We use that to generate a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Berlin" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
```

Create a String to represent the value of our [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

No need to define a formatting pattern. The `DateTimeFormatter` class can automatically localize a date-time representation to a human language and cultural norms defined by a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). Your desired format is already known to be the medium-length format commonly used in Germany.

Understand that a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) and a `Locale` are distinct and separate. One adjusts the meaning of the date-time to a wall-clock time of some geographic area on the globe. The other translates names of day or month, and determines comma versus period, and other such issues.

```
Locale locale = Locale.GERMANY;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale ( locale );
String output = zdt.format ( formatter );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt + " | output: " + output );
```

> input: 1449946800000 | instant: 2015-12-12T19:00:00Z | zdt: 2015-12-12T20:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin] | output: 12.12.2015 20:00:00

Answer (score 0):

`DateFormat` might be your friend to simplify the code (or `DateTimeFormatter` in case of Java 8).